# Client Certificate validation fails with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security

I am trying to create an application where I need to authenticate client using their certificates.
To generate the certificate, I followed [this](https://www.opencodez.com/java/implement-2-way-authentication-using-ssl.htm) tutorial

I generated the Java KeyStores with the public keys of client and the server.

I put them in the classpath of Spring boot project and set the properties as

```
server:
  port: 8443  # Define a custom port (instead of the default 8080)
  ssl:
    # The format used for the keystore
    key-store-type: jks
    key-store: classpath:MyServer.jks   # The path to the keystore containing the certificate
    key-password: password  # The password used to generate the certificate
    key-store-password: password
    trust-store: classpath:MyServer.jks   # Trust store that holds SSL certificates.
    trust-store-password: password    # Password used to access the trust store.
    trust-store-type: JKS   # Type of the trust store.
    client-auth: need   # Whether client authentication is wanted ("want") or needed ("need").
```

When I open the URL in the browser, I get the error as

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
This server could not prove that it is localhost; its security certificate does not specify Subject Alternative Names. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

But, when I change the property

```
client-auth: want
```

It opens the URL. It looks like it is not able to validate the client certificate. What I am missing here?

Comment: Which common names did you put into the certificate ?

Comment: I used as it is i.e. ```client.com``` as shown in the tutorial

Comment: Then define an alias "client.com" for localhost